# Ruby: Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, aptana

Note:  I retagged this question since I neglected to include the Aptana tag.  The error occurs when choosing "run server" in Aptana Studio 3.  Aptana tries to execute script/rails server, which results in the error below.

Perhaps an Aptana guru can answer?

---

I've looked through and tried the suggested solutions in all the similar questions I found.  Most of the questions did not have an accepted answer.

I've started a fresh Rails project to start on a tutorial, and when I try to run the server, I get the infamous:

> Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources

However, gem list shows:

> rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)

How can I be receiving this error when gem list clearly shows the gem is there?

How can I debug and resolve this issue?

My gemfile is:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.4' 
gem 'sqlite3' 
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require =>'sqlite3'
```

Comment: Try "bundle exec your command".

Comment: Ok, "bundle exec rails server" worked, as did "rails server".  Why won't "script/rails server" work?

Comment: Assuming you meant "rails s". To be fair I'm not entirely sure. I had my own share of problems with rake lately. Considering you're not running rails 3.1 yet I would suggest uninstalling rake 0.9.x until its more stable.

Comment: You don't need to specify `sqlite3-ruby` AND `sqlite3`. Just `sqlite3` is good enough.

Comment: maybe you need to run "bundle install" or the like?

Comment: I've run bundle install.

Answer (score 2):

You need to require rake gem in your Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.4' 
gem 'sqlite3' 
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require =>'sqlite3'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
```

now run `bundle install` make sure you are connected with internet.
now if you want to execute rake tasks then use `bundle exec rake task_name`

Comment: i have been at this for almost 2 days!!  You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in a subsequent update of Apatana, this error went away.  I now can run my application with the "Run Server" menu item again.

It's currently functional on Aptana 3.0.8.201201201658