# Could not find rake on capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano, unicorn

So I am attempting to get a capistrano deployment setup with an nginx/unicorn server, using RVM.

The deploy works, but when I attempt to interact with unicorn via capistrano i get an error like:

```
[~/source/quibbler/config]
$ cap unicorn:start
  * executing `unicorn:start'
  * executing "cd /u/apps/quibbler/current && bundle exec unicorn_rails -c /u/apps/quibbler/current/config/unicorn-production.rb -E production -D"
    servers: ["wwwtestvm.whf.app"]
    [wwwtestvm.whf.app] executing command
 ** [out :: wwwtestvm.whf.app] Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources
    command finished in 553ms
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@quibbler' -c 'cd /u/apps/quibbler/current && bundle exec unicorn_rails -c /u/apps/quibbler/current/config/unicorn-production.rb -E production -D'" on wwwtestvm.whf.app
```

I have searched the interwebs all night and can not find the solution.  If I copy paste the command into my shell it works so I am 99% sure it has to do with the RVM environment not being correct.

I have created a gist of my deploy and unicorn configs:

https://gist.github.com/1375736#file_deploy.rb
 https://gist.github.com/1375736#file_unicorn_production.rb

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to sannankhalid answer on this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340923/ruby-could-not-find-rake-0-9-2-in-any-of-the-sources) i was able to resolve it.

Short answer: add rake to your Gemfile, make sure you run `bundle install` so your Gemfile.lock gets updated, then deploy to your server, ayay!